# Rewrite rule not working without trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, loops, url-rewriting

I have a working rewrite rule to hide index.php?dir= from the URL.
So for instance if I try

```
www.example.com/folder/dir1/
```

it rewrites it to

```
www.example.com/folder/index.php?dir=dir1/
```

and that fine!
The trouble is if I remove the trailing slash from the URL i.e.

```
www.example.com/folder/dir1
```

it goes into a redirection loop!
My **complete** htaccess is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^dir=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^(.+)/? index.php?dir=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Please advice?

Comment: not sure , but try changing `RewriteRule ^(.+)/? index.php?dir=$1 [L,QSA]` to `RewriteRule ^(.+)? index.php?dir=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Did you mean `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` in last rule?

Comment: @Ofir: No it didn't help! The condition stays as it is..

Comment: @anubhava: No its without ! on purpose..

Comment: You could try adding `DirectorySlash Off`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!

Had to replace

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/? index.php?dir=$1 [L,QSA]
```

with

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)? index.php?dir=$1/ [L,QSA]
```

Thanks everyone for contributing..

Comment: The regexp makes no sense since  `^(.*)?` implies `^(.+)/?` and v.v.  I am also not sure why you want the trailing / on the dir parameter.

Comment: This also doesn't explain the looping.

Comment: My guess is that the '$1/' mainly made it work! My PHP requires an / at the end of directory to work. If it wasn't there, the directory called index.php which initiated redirect again.. Itss working like a charm now..

Answer (score 1):

(i) I am confused about the `RewriteBase /papers`.  This only makes sense in `DOCROOT/papers/.htaccess`. If this the location and is "folder" == papers?  If not then, I am not surprised that the rewrite engine is getting confused.  (ii) `%{REDIRECT_STATUS} is not 200 on  a subquery lookup to evaluate the default if MultiViews or DirectoryIndex is a match.

So before you do anything else:

- Validate that your base is correct, and if not fix it.
- Use `Options -MultiViews` if you don't use them.
- Check your system, vhost config and `DOCROOT/.htaccess` to see if a `DirectoryIndex` is specified. (Unlike rewrite rules which are only taken from the lowest `.htaccess`, all are scanned for directives such as this.)
- Replace the `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200` by

  ```
   RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_END}%{IS_SUBREQ} true
  ```

  and add the flag `E=END:true` to any rules that you want to force to end of the cycle as a match (similar to the Apache 2.4 [END] flag)  The extra %{IS_SUBREQ} prevents the rules being fired on a subquery.  You don't want this to happen unless you *really* know what you are doing.